# Hybris DataHub INVALID_LOCALE Exception

Tags: composition, sap-commerce-cloud

I have localized raw data item baseName. I want to send localized raw data item to DataHub. I read many documents, it writes send localized raw attribute value but I couldn't find the format of the localized attribute value. In the composition, it throws INVALID_LOCALE exception.

I am sending value for baseName, but how can I localized "XYZ"?

```
RawFragmentData rawFragmentData = new RawFragmentData();
final Map<String, String> line = new HashMap<>();
........        
line.put("baseName", "XYZ");
........        
rawFragmentData.setValueMap(line);
rawFragmentData.setType(type);
rawFragmentData.setDataFeedName(feedName);
rawFragmentData.setExtensionSource(Constants.DATAHUB_EXTENSION_SOURCE);
return rawFragmentData;
```

Comment: did you try look like impex?
line.put("baseName[lang=en]", "XYZ");

Comment: I try this before but it doesn't work. I found the solution at the end,  for localized value after adding line also add the locale value as line.put("isoCode", "en"); , and it works.

Answer (score 0):

e.g OOTB :

```
DefaultPartnerContributor.Java :-
    row.put(PartnerCsvColumns.COUNTRY_ISO_CODE, address.getCountry());
```

Same way you might have languageColumn for it, so just pass language value to it.